# Change sendAs email address in google mail api

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-forms

I have searched but cannot find any examples

What I am sending is

```
//Send Email
  var emailContents = 
  {
    to: techManagerEmail+","+organiserEmail,
    subject: "New Technical Support Request for " + eventName,
    body: "Event Name: "+eventName+ "\n\n"+"Event Room: "+eventRoom+ "\n\n"+eventDescription +"\n\n"+ allEvents + "\n\n" + "Google Folder: "+newFolderLink+"\n \n"+techTeam+" Calendar Link: "+ calendarLink + "\n\n" + "Date Submitted: " + submitionDate + " by: " + submitterEmail,
  };
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailContents);     
}
```

When I send, it sends as the user that created the form (me) when I want the person filling the form to be the sender - (I would also like the person filling the form to be the creator of the calendar event, but I think that may be a larger issue). It would also be nice to be able to change the display name.

I have looked at the api sendAs options but am struggling to work out how to use it or the syntax.

Any advice would be appreciated.

As requested, full code:

```
function onSubmit(e)
{

//Set General Variables  
  var formResponses = e.response.getItemResponses();
  var submitterEmail = e.response.getRespondentEmail();
  var submitionDate = e.response.getTimestamp();

  var eventName = formResponses[0].getResponse();
  var eventDescription = formResponses[1].getResponse();
  var moduleCode = formResponses[2].getResponse();
  var noStudents = formResponses[3].getResponse();  
  var organiser = formResponses[4].getResponse();
  var organiserEmail = formResponses[5].getResponse();
  var eventRoom = formResponses[6].getResponse();
  var techTeam = formResponses[7].getResponse();
  var supportRequired = formResponses[8].getResponse();
  var supportDescription = formResponses[9].getResponse();
  var equipmentRequired = formResponses[10].getResponse();
  var startDate = formResponses[11].getResponse();
  var nextAction = formResponses[18].getResponse();

  var supportDateNo = 11;
  var supportStartNo = 12;
  var eventStartNo = 13;
  var eventEndNo = 14;
  var supportEndNo = 15;
  var eventDaysDataNo = 16;
  var eventEndDateNo = 17;
  var nextActionNo = 18;  

  var nextActionSwitch = 1;
  var loopNo = 1;
  var calendarId =  CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calId);
  var allEvents ="";
  var day = 1000*60*60*24  
  var eventDescription = 'Organiser: ' + organiser + '\n \n' + 
                         'Module Code: ' + moduleCode + '\n \n' + 
                         'Description of the Event: ' + eventDescription  + '\n \n' + 
                         'Type of support: ' + supportRequired + '\n \n' + 
                         'Description of Support: ' + supportDescription + '\n \n'+
                         'Number of Students: ' + noStudents + '\n \n'+
                         'Equipment Required: ' + equipmentRequired + '\n\n';


//General Operations  
  if(organiserEmail==""){var organiserEmail = submitterEmail};  
  if(techTeam=="Performance Studios")
  {
    var calId = "****"; 
    var techManagerEmail = "****"; 
    var calendarLink = "****";
    var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('****');    
  };
 if(techTeam=="****")
  {
    var calId = "****"; 
    var techManagerEmail = "****"; 
    var calendarLink = "****";
    var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('****');     
  };
 if(techTeam=="****")
  {
    var calId = "****"; 
    var techManagerEmail = "****"; 
    var calendarLink = "****";
    var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('****');     
  };
 if(techTeam=="****")
  {
    var calId = "****"; 
    var techManagerEmail = "****"; 
    var calendarLink = "****";
    var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('****');     
  };


//create attachments
  var folderName = startDate + ' ' + eventName
  var newFolder = parentFolder.createFolder(folderName).getId(); 
  var newFolderLink = DriveApp.getFolderById(newFolder).getUrl(); 


//Calendar Creation Loop
  while(nextActionSwitch==1)
  {

  //Set Variables

    var supportDate   = formResponses[supportDateNo].getResponse();
    var supportStart = formResponses[supportStartNo].getResponse();  
    var eventStart = formResponses[eventStartNo].getResponse();
    var eventEnd = formResponses[eventEndNo].getResponse();
    var supportEnd = formResponses[supportEndNo].getResponse(); 
    var eventDaysData = formResponses[eventDaysDataNo].getResponse();      
    var eventEndDate = formResponses[eventEndDateNo].getResponse();
    var nextAction = formResponses[nextActionNo].getResponse();

    var indivudualTechDetails = "";
    var individualEventDetails = "";
    var individualRepeatDetails = "";


  //Time Operations 
    var eventEndDate = eventEndDate.replace(/-/g, "");
    if (eventDaysData == "All"){var eventDaysData = "MO,TU,WE,TH,FR,SA,SU,"};
    if (eventDaysData =="No Repeat"){var eventDaysData = ""; var eventEndDate = ""};
    if (eventEndDate == ""){var eventDaysData = ""}; 
    var alteredEndDate = Number(eventEndDate)+1;    
    var startDateTime = new Date(supportDate+"T"+supportStart+":00");
    var endDateTime = new Date(supportDate+"T"+supportEnd+":00.000Z");
    if (endDateTime<=startDateTime){var endDateTime = new Date(endDateTime.getTime() + day)};        
    var start = Utilities.formatDate(startDateTime, "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
    var end = Utilities.formatDate(endDateTime, "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
    var finalDescription = eventDescription;
    if (eventStart!=""){var finalDescription = eventName + ' Start Time: ' + eventStart +'\n' + eventName + ' End Time: ' + eventEnd + '\n \n' + eventDescription}; 

  //Date Display Operations
    var eventDay = startDateTime.getDate();
    var eventMonth = startDateTime.getMonth()+1;
    var eventYear = startDateTime.getFullYear();
    var eventEmailDate = eventDay+"/"+eventMonth+"/"+eventYear;
    var repeatEndDate = new Date(eventEndDate+"T"+supportStart+":000Z");
    var eventEndDay = repeatEndDate.getDate();
    var eventEndMonth = repeatEndDate.getMonth()+1;
    var eventEndYear = repeatEndDate.getFullYear();
    var eventEmailEndDate = eventEndDay+"/"+eventEndMonth+"/"+eventEndYear;


  //Create Event
    var event = 
    {
      summary: eventName,
      location: eventRoom,
      start: {dateTime: start, timeZone: "GMT"},
      end: {dateTime: end, timeZone: "GMT"},
      description: finalDescription,  
      colorId: 8,
      attendees: [{email: submitterEmail}, {email:organiserEmail}],
      attachments: [{fileId: newFolder, fileUrl:newFolderLink, title: eventName+" Folder"}],
      "recurrence": ["RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL="+alteredEndDate+";BYDAY="+eventDaysData]
    };

    if (eventEndDate == ""|| eventDaysData == "No Repeat")
    {
      var event = 
      {
        summary: eventName,
        location: eventRoom,
        start: {dateTime: start, timeZone: "GMT"},
        end: {dateTime: end, timeZone: "GMT"},
        description: finalDescription,  
        colorId: 8,
        attendees: [{email: submitterEmail}, {email:organiserEmail}],
        attachments: [{fileId: newFolder, fileUrl:newFolderLink, title: eventName+" Folder"}],
      };
    };
    var eventLink = Calendar.Events.insert(event, calId, {SendNotifications: true, supportsAttachments:true}).getHtmlLink();


  //Event Details
    var individualTechDetails =
      "Instance: " + loopNo + "\n\n" +    
      "Start Date: " + eventEmailDate + "\n\n" +
      "Tech Start Time: " + supportStart  + "\n\n" +
      "Tech End Time: " + supportEnd + "\n\n";

    if (eventStart != ""){var individualEventDetails = 
      "Event Start Time: " + eventStart + "\n\n" +
      "Event End Time: " + eventEnd + "\n\n"}; 

    if (eventEndDate != ""){ var individualRepeatDetails =   
      "Repeats: " + eventDaysData + "\n\n"+
      "End Date: " + eventEndDate+"\n\n"};

    var combinedEventDetails = individualTechDetails + individualEventDetails + individualRepeatDetails + "Event Link: "+ eventLink;
    var allEvents = allEvents + combinedEventDetails + "\n\n -- \n \n";


  //Set Loop Values
    var nextActionSwitch = 0;
    if (nextAction=="Add dates with a different pattern")
    {         
      var nextActionSwitch = 1;
      var loopNo = loopNo +1;          
      var supportDateNo = supportDateNo +8;
      var supportStartNo = supportStartNo +8;
      var eventStartNo = eventStartNo +8;
      var eventEndNo = eventEndNo +8;
      var supportEndNo = supportEndNo +8;
      var eventDaysDataNo = eventDaysDataNo +8;
      var eventEndDateNo = eventEndDateNo +8;
      var nextActionNo = nextActionNo +8;

    };
  };      


//Send Email
  var requestorEmails = submitterEmail + ", " + organiserEmail;
  if (organiserEmail == submitterEmail){requestorEmails = organiserEmail};
  var emailContents = 
  {
    to: techManagerEmail+","+requestorEmails,
    subject: "New Technical Support Request for " + eventName,
    body: "Event Name: "+eventName+ "\n\n"+"Event Room: "+eventRoom+ "\n\n"+eventDescription +"\n\n"+ allEvents + "\n\n" + "Google Folder: "+newFolderLink+"\n \n"+techTeam+" Calendar Link: "+ calendarLink + "\n\n" + "To create another event: ****" + "\n\n" + "Date Submitted: " + submitionDate + " by: " + submitterEmail,
    name: techTeam + " Technical Support Requests",
  };
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailContents);     
}
```

Comment: Can u show the full code snippet? Because this code doesn't include where variables are defined.

Comment: It looks like what you are trying to do, is something like employees requesting technical support, and depending upon the type of support, an email is sent from the department that would be providing the support.  If you have a GSuite account, you could set up aliases, and send an email from the alias depending upon what department is in charge of providing the support.  Another option would be to have the script make a POST request to an Apps Script Web App in the Drive of the account that is providing the support.  Then that script could send an email from the account.

Answer (score 0):

There are limited ways you can achieve this. The only way to achieve that is by logging with the account of the person filling the form. If you're running the script automatically via a trigger, just set the trigger with this account.

There's an open issue about this on Apps Script tracker:
***[Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36751837)***

*Hope this answers your question!!*